# tkinter progress bar does not update when window loses focus

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I have the following code where run is a method which does stuff and updates the progress bar incrementally as it does the stuff.

```
window = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(text = 'Analyze Data', width=15, height=3,bg='gray', fg='black')
button.bind("<Button-1>", run)
button.pack(pady=10)
progress = ttk.Progressbar(window, orient = tk.HORIZONTAL, mode = 'determinate')
progress.pack(pady=10)
window.mainloop()
```

It works fine, aside from the fact that if the window ever loses focus the progress bar no longer updates (even if the window regains focus). Why is this happening and is there a way to make the progress bar update even if the window loses focus?

I update the progress bar in the run function with:

```
progress['value'] = progress['value']+1
window.update_idletasks()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, changing from window.update_idletasks() to window.update() after updating the progress bar value solved the problem